# What is easiest way of changing XML at given XPath in scala?

Tags: xml, scala, xpath, scala-xml

```
val template = <root>
    <component>
        <mother-board>
            <manufacturer>
                <name>
                </name
            </manufacturer>
            <price>
                555
            </price>
            <chipset>
                Intel
            </chipset>
        </mother-board>
    </component>
</root>

val xPaths = Map("root/component/mother-board/manufacturer/name" -> "Asus")

val output = <root>
    <component>
        <mother-board>
            <manufacturer>
                <name>
                  Asus
                </name>
            </manufacturer>
            <price>
                555
            </price>
            <chipset>
                Intel
            </chipset>
        </mother-board>
    </component>
</root>
```

The real template is over 250 lines and the number of xpaths that need to be populated is over 70. Any suggestions regarding libraries or any other approach that can accomplish this is welcome. Thank you.

**Update to add info about my approach**
What I have done so far that does not work:
I create XML based on XPaths available. But if the order in which XPaths are processed changes, the XML changes too which is not acceptable to my use case.

```
object Main extends App {
  val props = Map(
    "a/b/c" -> "val1",
    "a/b/d/f" -> "val3",
    "a/b/d/e" -> "val2"
  )

  println(props.keys.foldLeft(<root/>: Node)((acc, current) => {
    create(Elem(acc.prefix, acc.label, acc.attributes, acc.scope, true, acc.child: _*), current.split("/").toList, current, props)
  }))

  def create(node: Elem, path: List[String], completePath: String, propMap: Map[String, String]): Node = {
    if(path.size > 0) {
      val current = path.head
      node.child.filter(x => x.label.equals(current)).headOption.map(childToTraverse => {
        val newChild = create(Elem(null, childToTraverse.label, childToTraverse.attributes, childToTraverse.scope, false, childToTraverse.child: _*), path.tail, completePath, propMap)
        node.copy(child = node.child.filter(x => !x.label.equals(current)) ++ newChild)
      }).getOrElse({
        val newNode = Elem(null, current, node.attributes, node.scope, false)
        val newChild = create(newNode, path.tail, completePath, propMap)
        node.copy(child = node.child ++ newChild)
      })
    }
    else {
      node.copy(child = new Text(propMap.get(completePath).getOrElse("Value Not Available")))
    }
  }
}
```

Problem:

For input:

```
"a/b/c" -> "val1",
"a/b/d/f" -> "val3",
"a/b/d/e" -> "val2"
```

It generates:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>
                val1
            </c>
            <d>
                <f>
                    val3
                </f>
                <e>
                    val2
                </e>
            </d>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

For input:

```
"a/b/c" -> "val1",
"a/b/d/e" -> "val2",
"a/b/d/f" -> "val3"
```

It generates:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>
                val1
            </c>
            <d>
                <e>
                    val2
                </e>
                <f>
                    val3
                </f>
            </d>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

Notice the difference in two XMLs generated from identical XPaths processed in different order.
I know the correct order. So I wanted to have template and change the template based on XPaths instead of generating the XML from scratch.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I have tried creating the xml from the xpaths. But that doesnt work because different orders of xpaths gives slightly different order in xml which is not acceptable.

Comment: If you show us your attepts and explain what is wrong with result we can try to find the problem.

Comment: @talex: Please take a look at the updates.